# Debian Jessie shutting down too fast (<1 second)

Tags: shutdown, systemd, syslog, debian-jessie

I recently have bought an SSD for my laptop and installed fresh Debian Jessie on it (I used Wheezy before). As a result, most operations on the laptop have sped up, and one operation in particular even drastically so. In fact, it now takes about 1 second for a `sudo shutdown now` to complete. Even in real-time systems like QNX a 1-second shutdown is considered hasty, especially if any network interfaces have been up, so I don't think this can be normal. The problem is, I can't find any relevant error messages anywhere. The last second of `syslog` shows nothing special (I took the liberty to remove `openobex` messages which I believe are not important):

```
Oct 12 23:58:21 hostname kernel: [17080.034445] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct 12 23:58:21 hostname kernel: [17080.050734] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
Oct 12 23:58:21 hostname kernel: [17080.050754] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
Oct 12 23:58:21 hostname kernel: [17080.050763] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
Oct 12 23:58:21 hostname kernel: [17080.052458] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Oct 12 23:58:21 hostname kernel: [17080.098666] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Oct 12 23:58:21 hostname rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="574" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

I checked out [this `systemd` bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784720) which seems unrelated upon inspection. The bug is fixed in my release `systemd 215-17+deb8u2`, and `rsyslog` reports to exit on `SIGTERM`, not on `SIGKILL`.

Have anyone else encountered this issue? I realize it looks more like a nice feature to many users, so they won't google for it or report it anywhere until they lose data. Any suggestions on how to diagnose it or where to look for more info?

### EDIT:

Since I have `sshd` installed, I took the opportunity to investigate its behavior. Indeed, when I start and stop the service manually (e.g. `service ssh stop`), appropriate messages appear in `/var/log/auth`. There's also a noticeable delay when the service is started or stopped. But when I `shutdown` or `systemctl isolate runlevel1.target`, no message about `sshd` going down appears.

The service is configured with default configuration parameters, and it is managed via `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

My `shutdown.target` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
DefaultDependencies=no
RefuseManualStart=yes
```

Adding a symlink `/etc/rc1.d/K00ssh` makes `sshd` stop correctly when the system goes to runlevel 1, but that's not a real solution: I'm not supposed to create such symlinks manually on a freshly installed system, and such symlinks are deprecated anyway in favor of `.service` files.

Comment: Maybe you can create some scripts and put them in the `etc/init.d` with the goal to see if is all well executed when you do the shutdown. Maybe a `sleep 1m` and some `echo` in some log...  Follow [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48974/66388) to take some hints.

Comment: I don't know exactly how systemd on Jessie does it, so you might have to look around a little, but there should be a `shutdown` or similarly named target that you can edit. Right near the end, just add something like `sleep 600` (600s = 10 minutes); that should give you time to review any on-screen output for anomalies.

Comment: `/etc/init.d` scripts are executed, but that's not the way `systemd` is supposed to work (and I don't have the required symlinks for all my services). The problem is that `*.service` files seem to be taken into account on startup, but not on shutdown.

Comment: @DragonLord I really mentioned the SSD thing just in case, I don't think it's related to the issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty solution, I have switched to `System V` (which created appropriate symlinks in `/etc/rcX.d/`) and then back to `SystemD`:

```
sudo apt-get install sysvinit
sudo apt-get remove systemd
reboot
sudo apt-get install systemd systemd-ui
sudo apt-get remove sysvinit
```